# Prove $3^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom {n} {k} 2^k$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, summation, binomial-coefficients

> Let $n$ be a nonnegative integer. Prove that
>   \begin{align}
> 3^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \dbinom{n}{k} 2^k .
> \end{align}

I know that $2^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \dbinom{n}{k}$, but how to integrate the $2^k$ into this sum?

Answer (score 7):

How do you derive  $$\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}=2^n?$$ 
For positive integer $n$

$$\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}x^k=(1+x)^n$$

Answer (score 3):

If you don’t know the binomial theorem, you can still prove it using a combinatorial argument.

$3^n$ is the number of $n$-letter strings that you can make using only $a$’s, $b$’s, and $c$’s; that counts them all at once, but we can count them in another way as well. One way to form such a string is to pick first which positions in the string won’t be $a$’s. If we decide to have $k$ letters that aren’t $a$’s, there are $\binom{n}k$ ways to decide where to put them; the other $n-k$ letters will of course be $a$’s. Then for each of those $k$ positions that **won’t** be occupied by $a$’s, we have to decide whether to put a $b$ or a $c$ there. That’s a two-way choice, and we have to make $k$ such choices independently, so there are $2^k$ ways to make these choices. Thus, there are altogether $\binom{n}k2^k$ strings that have a total of $k$ $b$’s and $c$’s. To get the total number of strings, just add up these numbers $\binom{n}k2^k$ for all possible values of $k$, i.e., for $k=0$ to $k=n$:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k2^k\;.$$

Since this is just another way of counting the $n$-letter strings containing nothing but $a$’s, $b$’s, and $c$’s, it must be $3^n$.

Answer (score 2):

It is $$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}  2^k \cdot 1^{n-k}=(1+2)^n$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a combinatorial interpretation:

The lefthand side counts functions from $[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\} $ to $X=\{*,1,2\}$. We can count the left hand side a different way. Namely, it is the disjoint union over all $0 \leq k \leq n$ of functions $[n] \rightarrow X$  so that $k$ elements of $[n]$ get sent to $*$. Fixing a $k$, we have $n$ choose $k$ subsets that can be sent to $*$ and for the complement I must choose a function $[n] \rightarrow [2]$. Since there are $2^k $ of these, we recover $ 3^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}2^k$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $3^n=(2+1)^n{}{}{}{}{}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the alphabet $\{a,b,c\}$. Let $W$ be the set of $n$-letter words over the alphabet $A$. There are $3^n$ words in $W$.

We count the words another way. For any $k$, where $0\le k\le n$, let $W_k$ be the set of $n$-letter words over $A$ that have exactly $k$ $c$'s. The **location** of the $c$'s can be chosen in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways. For any such choice, the rest of the locations can be filled with $a$'s and/or $b$'s in $2^k$ ways. Thus there are $\binom{n}{k}2^k$ words in $W_k$.

But $W$ is the disjoint union of the $W_k$. It follows that $3^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}2^k$.

Comment: The generating function approach of lab bhattacharjee is nice. It is fun though to give *combinatorial* proofs of combinatorial identities, by counting the same thing in two different ways.

Comment: I agree. I appreciate both ways, but I always appreciate combinatorial proofs because 99% of the time they give me the 'ah-ha' moment.

Comment: I agree about the attractiveness of combinatorial arguments, but there is an "ah-ha" moment also with $(1+x)^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the right hand side looks a LOT like the Binomial theorem....

Answer (score 1):

Remember the binomial theorem $$(x+y)^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k y^{n-k}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using Binomial Theorem, $(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}x^k$

Putting $x=2$ gives you your answer.

See combinatorial proof of binomial theorem http://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/binomial_thm/combinatorial.pdf